# Sitecore Version Upgrade 8.0 to 8.2

Tags: versions, update-packages

***Please advise me how to upgrade from 8.0 to 8.2 update 3 with WFFM
module in local and also UAT and PRD environment.***

What would be the following process step by step.Please suggest .

Comment: Have you gone through the upgrade guide on dev.sitecore.net portal?

Comment: As Joao Neto mentioned below, there are several blogs and the guide he mentioned have all the necessary steps described. On the other hand I agree this is a very broad question to be asked here, please let us know if you have any specific query for the upgrade process else my 2 cents to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find several blog posts on how to upgrade, but I can provide here the initial steps.

1. Open the documentation page of the Sitecore version you want to update to and download the upgrade guide. In your case, open https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/82/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_82_Update3.aspx.

[image]

2. Check the prerequisites in the upgrade guide

[image]

3. If your current Sitecore version is not supported for this upgrade then you need to read the upgrade guide of the minimum version supported. e.g. Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151003 (Initial Release). It might require you updating first to one version, then to another, until you reach the desired version. Also, you should check the **Express Migration tool** which can give you a hand on that.

I strongly advise you to read through all the provided documentation. Also, you need to know that you'll have to update legacy/deprecated code in your Visual Studio solution, Sitecore modules and etc.

The upgrade guide tells you the minimum you need to know.

Comment: Hello @Joao please delete your comment. I am not able to delete the post.